# I get a KeyError when trying to plot these group of dataframes with Pandas

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I get a keyerror for "Displacement" when I try to plot Force against Displacement with pandas for these group of dataframes. Please help.

The link to the excel sheet being used:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/f8lnp973ojv3ish/neurospheress.xlsx?dl=0

I tried clearing any space in the column titles but it doesn't work

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_excel('neurospheress.xlsx', sep='\s*,\s*', sheet_name = 'LS')

df1 = data.iloc[:80,:2]
df2 = data.iloc[:80,2:4]
df3 = data.iloc[:80,4:]
dfs = [df1,df2,df3]

for i,df in enumerate(dfs):
    plt.plot(df['Displacement'], df['Force'], linestyle='--', alpha= 0.8, label='df{}'.format(i))
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below solution works, it basically adds two things to your solution

a) Skip the first row from excel 
b) Rename the column names for df2 and df3

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_excel('neurospheress.xlsx', sep='\s*,\s*', sheet_name = 'LS',skiprows=1)

df1 = data.iloc[:80,:2]
df2 = data.iloc[:80,2:4]
df3 = data.iloc[:80,4:]
dfs = [df1,df2,df3]

df2.rename(columns={'Force.1':'Force','Displacement.1':'Displacement'},inplace=True)
df3.rename(columns={'Force.2':'Force','Displacement.2':'Displacement'},inplace=True)

print(data.columns)
print(df1.columns)
print(df2.columns)

for i,df in enumerate(dfs):
    plt.plot(df['Displacement'], df['Force'], linestyle='--', alpha= 0.8, label='df{}'.format(i))
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```